# Linux Management

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, debian

We are a startup in bootstrap developing code written in Java.

- We are purchasing custom desktops - not branded desktops - hence they come without an OS. We did insist on TPM chips for our motherboard.
- We would like to deploy debian or ubuntu on all machines and manage the same from a single linux based server or cloud.
- We want to restrict the software packages installed on each machine, manage updates and access rights for individuals.
- we want a way of storing recovery keys for the encrypted drives / folders  of users centrally so that Management can gain access in case it's required.

We know of Spacewalk from Redhat, but it sounds like support will end in 2017 and then Redhat would slowly cease supporting it. We are not in a position to look at landscape, satellite etc - these are very expensive solutions.

Could you advice an alternative zero cost solution or something that is extremely low cost?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!